# Mathplotlib update 3dplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use the methods 'set_data' and 'set_3d_properties' for a matplotlib.pyplot.plot object.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class animationObj(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.fig= plt.figure()
    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    self.plot = []
    self.plot.append(self.ax.plot([0], [0], [0], 'bo', markersize=10)[0])
    self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self, frames=range(0,10), interval=50, repeat_delay=1000)

def show(self):
    return plt.show()

def __call__(self, i):

    self.plot[0].set_data([x[i]], [y[i]])
    self.plot[0].set_3d_properties([z[i]], 'z')

    return self.plot[0]
```

I have made use of the following example: http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/simple_3danim.html

But it seems that the set_data and set_3d_properties are not working correctly. Does anyone know what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was not in the code for updating the x, y, an z data, but the mistake was that when the animation was created for the first time, the range for the x, y and z axis was set for the first data set. So setting a range for x, y and z solved the problem:

```
self.ax.set_xlim([0, 5])
self.ax.set_ylim([0, 5])
self.ax.set_zlim([0, 5])
```